# converting java to perl (md5)

Tags: md5

I am trying converting java to perl (md5)program.
How can i do following two programs same output MD5 sum.

Java

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class Hash 
{ 
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception 
   { 
       MessageDigest md5    = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       String        plain  = "abcd1234"; 
       BigInteger    digest = new BigInteger(md5.digest(plain.getBytes("UTF-8"))); 
       System.out.println( digest.abs() ); 
   } 
}
```

Perl

```
use Digest::MD5 'md5_hex'; 
use Math::BigInt; 

my $plain  = "abcd1234"; 
my $digest = Math::BigInt::->from_hex(md5_hex $plain); 
print $digest, "\n";
```

I Think,

Java:

```
BigInteger digest = new BigInteger(md5.digest(plain.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Perl:

```
my $digest = Math::BigInt::->from_hex(md5_hex $plain);
```

here is diffrent output MD5 sum.
I want to edit perl source.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BigInteger()` call requires a byte array containing the two's complement binary representation of the number. You need to use the sign-magnitude constructor:

```
public BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)
```

So, your Java code should be:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class Hash 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    { 
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        String plain = "abcd1234"; 
        BigInteger digest = new BigInteger(1, md5.digest(plain.getBytes("UTF-8"))); 
        System.out.println(digest.abs()); 
    } 
}
```

Your Perl code didn't quite work for me, either. My version of `Math::BigInt` requires a string representation of the hex value, like so:

```
use Digest::MD5 'md5_hex'; 
use Math::BigInt; 

my $plain = "abcd1234"; 
my $digest = Math::BigInt::->from_hex('0x' . md5_hex($plain)); 
print $digest, "\n";
```

When I run those two commands, I get the same digest value displayed.